# How to introduce Domain Driven Design to co-programmers?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Tomorrow i need to show small presentation about DDD approach.

It should contain 2 main points:
"What is Domain Driven Design?"
"How can we use it?"

I would be glad if i could see some ideas how to 'implement' first point of my 'presentation interface'.

Asking because I'm not making presentations everyday and i`m little bit confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat hard to understand whether your problem is a lack of DDD knowledge, or just how to present it.

"What is Domain Driven Design" - grab a good overview from http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly

"How can we use it". You can't really just "use it". You must identify the parts of it that makes sense for your business.

- You can take advantage of the big focus on understanding and modeling the business, and creating a common language in speech, code and documentation.
- You can use ideas related to software architecture, like using repositories, entities and value objects.
- You can take note of the principles for good design and code quality, like intention-revealing interfaces, side-effect-free functions, etc.
- You can try to pass on knowledge of refactoring, and strategies relating to larger systems.

Some are low hanging fruit in concept understanding, others are hard to impose without personal interest.

Comment: @Rune, both - lack of DDD knowledge & problems presenting it. I see it as lack of knowledge mostly because i haven`t participated in project which follows this approach from day 0 to the end. At the moment, source code already is designed trying to follow DDD. Problem is - that it`s mostly made by myself, others are not familiar with this. It can't continue like this. They have to be properly introduced or source will be refactored to something that follows as i say "helpers and common code everywhere". :)

Comment: I can easily understand that. At least make sure you strongly urge them to read "Domain driven design quickly"; that might get a few on board. Have it ready on a fileshare when you do the presentation even, to make sure the effort needed to check it out is as little as possible..

Answer (score 1):

Amis,

Is to translate the current slide to your needs (its in portuguese-brazil) -> [Slide](http://www.slideshare.net/rponte/entendendo-domaindriven-design)

Explain that DDD isnt a tech or methodology, but is more like an approach that gather various concepts, techniques and principles with focus on domain logic.

Explain about ubiquitous language, Layered architecture, Domain Patterns, and diffs about current approach and ddd approach, later on enlighten then with the benefits of using DDD over the current methods and add a conclusion on your presentation..

Hopes it helped ya.

Comment: "diffs about current approach and ddd approach", this one is exactly what i had in mind - to show DDD as next step of evolution of our approach. And those wouldn't be lies.

Answer (score 0):

**[This](http://hinchcliffe.org/archive/2005/03/20/189.aspx)** mind map sorted my mind.